# Publish nUnit test results to TFS build server?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, nunit, msbuildcommunitytasks

I'm using MSBuild Community Tasks to do automated unit testing on my TFS build server like this:

```
<Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Build">
  <!-- blah blah blah -->

  <NUnit Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)" />
</Target>
```

When I queue a build in TFS, this produces a `TestResult.xml` file in the build directory.  TFS doesn't know how to interpret this though.  On the information page for the completed build, it still says:

> No test results

This is not unexpected, since TFS doesn't interoperate with nUnit out of the box.  Is it possible to get nUnit's results to publish back to TFS?

Comment: have you tried using the nunit adapter for VS instead?
http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2

Comment: @allen:  Yes, I've used that, but I don't have VS on the build server, and nor have I seen how to get VS to report test results back to the build controller in TFS.